# Count value pairs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a set of data in excel where each row has (amongst other things) two values and I want is to generate a sorted list of all pairings.

Example data:

```
Val1  Val2
------------
A     B
B     A
C     A
B     C
A     B
C     A
etc..
```

Example output:

```
Val1  Val2  Count
------------------
A     B     2
B     A     1
B     C     1
C     A     2
```

Is there a way to do this without writing VBA code.

**Edit:** I should add that my dataset is growing and I would prefer a solution that would update automatically as new data is entered.

Comment: May I ask why the aversion to VBA code?

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to concatenate the two columns together, perform do a `COUNTIF()` on that column and finally remove all duplicate rows.

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Assume: Row 1 is header row, and row 2 is the first row of data (`A B`).

### Steps

1. Enter in D2: `=A2 & "|||" & B2` and copy down to D3:D999
   (Use some rare string like `"|||"`)
2. Enter in C2: `=COUNTIF(D:D, D2)` and copy down to C3:C999
3. Copy column C:C, then Paste Special as value to column C:C (`Alt-E > S > V > Enter`)
4. Select column A:D, then sort by column D
5. Enter in E2: `=IF(OR(ROW(D2)=2, C2=1, AND(C2>1,D2<>D1)), "Keep", "Delete")` and copy down to E3:E999
6. Turn on AutoFilter (`Alt-D > F > F`)
7. Select "Delete" in column E drop-down list
8. Select row 2:999, then right cilck > Delete
   (Some `#REF!` may be shown in column E, which is normal)
9. Turn off AutoFilter (`Alt-D > F > F`)
10. Delete dummy column D:E

Answer (score 0):

Use the `countifs` macro.

Original Table:

```
      A     B
    Val1  Val2
    ------------
 1  A     B
 2  B     A
 3  C     A
 4  B     C
 5  A     B
 6  C     A
    etc...
```

The macro in this case is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A6, A1, B1:B6, B1)
```

Which reads "If in range A1:A6 there is an A, and if in range B1:B6 there is B, count it."

This will result in something like this (with COUNTIFS in column G):

```
      E    F     G
    Val1  Val2  Count
    ------------------
 1  A     B     2
 2  B     A     1
 3  B     C     1
 4  C     A     2
```

One could make the ranges absolute:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6, A1, $B$1:$B$6, B1)
```

Or use a truth table (or key) so the `COUNTIFS` isn't self-referential.

```
      H    I    
    Keys1 Keys2 
    ------------
 1  A     A     
 2  B     B     
 3  C     C
```

Which would help make a countifs that would gather data from the original dataset, but compare to a referential table, like so:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6, H1, $B$1:$B$6, I1)
```

So this is the same thing, but now data on the table can update and be sorted without making the `COUNTIFS` inaccurate.